# Backpropagation on Neural Network in Python

Tags: python, neural-network

I've implemented a neural network (deep autoencoder), on which I'm trying to perform backpropagation. The network consist of sigmoid activation functions and a softmax activation function at the output layer. To calculate the error, I use the Cross Entropy error function. The data input is bag of word matrices, where the words are divided by the length of the document to normalize the data.

I'm using the method Conjugate Gradient in order to find local minima. My problem is basically that the error is rising during backpropagation. I believe that it has something to do with me calculating the gradient wrong?

The code to calculate the error and gradient is given below:

```
def get_grad_and_error(self,weights,weight_sizes,x):

    weights = self.__convert__(weights, weight_sizes)
    x = append(x,ones((len(x),1),dtype = float64),axis = 1)
    xout, z_values = self.__generate_output_data__(x, weights)        

    f = -sum(x[:,:-1]*log(xout)) # Cross-entropy error function

    # Gradient
    number_of_weights = len(weights)
    gradients = []
    delta_k = None
    for i in range(len(weights)-1,-1,-1):
        if i == number_of_weights-1:
            delta = (xout-x[:,:-1])
            grad = dot(z_values[i-1].T,delta)
        elif i == 0:
            delta = dot(delta_k,weights[i+1].T)*z_values[i]*(1-z_values[i])
            delta = delta[:,:-1]
            grad = dot(x.T,delta)
        else:
            delta = dot(delta_k,weights[i+1].T)*z_values[i]*(1-z_values[i])
            delta = delta[:,:-1]
            grad = dot(z_values[i-1].T,delta)                
        delta_k = delta
        gradients.append(grad)

    gradients.reverse()
    gradients_formatted = []
    for g in gradients:
        gradients_formatted = append(gradients_formatted,reshape(g,(1,len(g)*len(g[0])))[0])

    return f,gradients_formatted
```

To calculate the output of the network I use following method:

```
def __generate_output_data__(self, x, weight_matrices_added_biases):
    z_values = []

    for i in range(len(weight_matrices_added_biases)-1):
        if i == 0:
            z = dbn.sigmoid(dot(x,weight_matrices_added_biases[i]))
        else:
            z = dbn.sigmoid(dot(z_values[i-1],weight_matrices_added_biases[i]))    

        z = append(z,ones((len(x),1),dtype = float64),axis = 1)
        z_values.append(z)

    xout = dbn.softmax(dot(z_values[-1],weight_matrices_added_biases[-1]))
    return xout, z_values
```

I calculate the sigmoid and softmax values as follows:

```
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1./(1+exp(-x))

def softmax(x):
    numerator = exp(x)
    denominator = numerator.sum(axis = 1)
    denominator = denominator.reshape((x.shape[0],1))
    softmax = numerator/denominator
    return softmax
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could be of assistance? Please let me know if you need me to elaborate on any of the above info? Thanks.

Comment: Try to tidy up your code a bit - for example, your cross-entropy function is never used, so maybe it's irrelevant to talk about here and use it in the code. You do a lot of matrix/vector reshaping - a simple -1/1 error can hide anywhere. Perhaps try a simple network with one neuron in a layer and debug your code to verify if the gradient is pulling the weights in the proper direction. For one training case and backpropagation step afterwards it should be impossible for error to increase.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The cross-entropy function is definitely called. I just haven't posted all the code, thus I believe that would be a distraction from the actual problem - the gradient?! I'm quite sure that there should be no problem with the matrix sizing throughout the code. I still believe that I need some help with the math, when calculating the gradient?